# "Cannot file: mysql.pro" mysql driver for qt error

Tags: mysql, qt, driver

I have been spending the whole day trying to figure out how to compile the mysql driver for qt so that i can import a database into table view, but nothing that I have found has helped me out. I am currently using qt 5.5 and Mysql server 5.7. My issue is that I get a certain error when running the following command in the qt command prompt:

set mysql=C:\PROGRA~2\MySQL\MYSQLS~1.7

cd C:\Qt\5.5\mingw492_32\plugins\sqldrivers

qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=%mysql%\include" "LIBS+=%mysql%\lib\libmysql.lib" -o Makefile mysql.pro

mingw32-make

And I get the error "cannot find file: mysql.pro"

I don't understand. Am I missing the file in the directory? Or have I not installed qt properly?

Comment: Maybe you should reconfigure Qt and enable the mysql driver there.

Comment: I tried that, but unfortunately I can't seem to find anything even related to the mysql driver in the qt maintenance tool when trying to add new components.

Comment: I am talking about the command line configure executable that you use to configure Qt before you build it from source. Not the GUI maintanance tool.

Comment: I am relatively new at Qt, and don't know much beyond the usage of the actual program. Do you think you could tell me what exactly I must do for this?

Comment: Is that the only error you get?